# Discord bot .js queryselector

Tags: javascript, discord, queryselector

I'm trying to implement a js code in my discord bot. So I take some code on the net to try if it was working and now, I'm trying to use queryselector like this :

```js
if (msg.content === "!GuessNumber"){
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1;
      const guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
      const lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
      const lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');
      const guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
      const guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');
      let guessCount = 1;
      let resetButton;
```

But I have this error

```
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Client.<anonymous> (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/index.js:18:23)
    at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/Users/zep/Documents/GitHub/Bot-discord/my-bot/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:801:20)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can someone help me to debug this and use the code from https://github.com/mdn/learning-area/blob/master/javascript/introduction-to-js-1/first-splash/number-guessing-game.html for my bot ? 
I this to try how it works , Thanks

Comment: If this is running on a server / with node, it does not have DOM to query. (You cannot search for a guess field if there is no HTML to search in) Where do you want to get your "guessField" from? a /command?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot use

```js
      const guesses = document.querySelector('.guesses');
      const lastResult = document.querySelector('.lastResult');
      const lowOrHi = document.querySelector('.lowOrHi');
      const guessSubmit = document.querySelector('.guessSubmit');
      const guessField = document.querySelector('.guessField');
```

Because "Document" is something that can be used inside a HTML-supported javascript file.

You may search for a replacement to this at https://discord.js.org as it might help. I will also check myself.

I actually am not able to understand what exactly you are wanting to do there, Do you want to make the user (the person who executes the command) guess the number, or you want the bot to guess the number of the user by the bot.